# SerializerMethodField not showing all fields of serializer when no FK relationship exists

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

**Desired result:**

I have a nested API response as shown below:

```
{
    "subject": {
        "name": "math",
        "teacher": <uuid>,
        "teacher_name": "John"
    },
    "grade": 1,
}
```

`teacher_name` is a custom field which uses `teacher`.

It works when `subject` and `grade` are set. But when the FK `subject` is `null`, I get this response:

**Unwanted result**

```
{
    "subject": {
        "name": "",
        "teacher": null,
    },
    "grade": 1,
}
```

**Question:**

I would want `teacher_name` to also appear. I have tried setting it up as a `serializers.CharField`

```
teacher_name= serializers.CharField(
    source="teacher.name",
    read_only=True,
    allow_blank=True,
    default=None,
)
```

and a `serializers.SerializerMethodField`

```
teacher_name= serializers.SerializerMethodField()
def get_subject_teacher(self, obj):
    return obj.teacher.name
```

But to no success.

Here is my serializer for the nested API:

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    subject = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    def get_subject(self, obj):
        filtered_obj = getattr(obj, "subject", None)
        return SubjectSerializer(filtered_obj).data

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = (
            "subject",
            "grade",
        )

class SubjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    teacher_name= serializers.CharField(
        source="teacher.name",
        read_only=True,
        allow_blank=True,
        default=None,
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Subject
        fields = (
            "name",
            "teacher",
            "teacher_name",
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
class SubjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    teacher_name= serializers.CharField(
        source="teacher.name",
        allow_blank=True,
        default=None,
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Subject
        fields = (
            "name",
            "teacher",
            "teacher_name",
        )
```

Comment: `teacher_name` still isn't shown.

Comment: @mionnaise I edited my answer, the problem was `read_only=True`. Then you can ensure that the request is read only in the view.

Comment: thanks!!! removing read_only fixed it! Can you please explain why `read_only` was hiding the field when nested?